# React native expo, You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app()

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

In my project am using React native firebase to get Analytics and my project is expo bare flow, I just followed this https://rnfirebase.io/ Document but while running the app am getting error like

```
backend.js:2173 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3):
Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.

See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.
Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
```

My Android MainApplication.java

```
import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage; <---added for firebase   
private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
@Override
public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
  return BuildConfignfig.DEBUG;
}

@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
  packages.add(new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage());<---- added for firebase
  return packages;
}
```

package.json

```
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^13.0.1",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^13.0.1",
"@types/npm": "^7.19.0",
"apisauce": "^0.15.1",
"base-64": "^0.1.0",
"expo": "~42.0.1",
"expo-blur": "~9.0.3",
"expo-camera": "^11.2.2",
"expo-linear-gradient": "~9.2.0",
"expo-secure-store": "~10.2.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
"expo-updates": "~0.8.1",
"native-base": "^2.15.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "~0.63.4",
```

I tried with config-plugin https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/ also but no use, the error is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

## **The Problem**

I just encountered this issue and managed to solve it.  Basically, if you're using Expo Go, you can't rely on the react native firebase packages (eg: `@react-native-firebase/functions`).

Previously, I was trying to use cloud functions in my app like this:

```
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';

// some other code

functions()
  .httpsCallable('annotateImage')({
    image: {
      content: result.assets[0].base64,
    },
    features: [
      {
        type: 'TEXT_DETECTION',
      },
    ],
    imageContext: {
      languageHints: ['en'],
    },
  }).then(// blah blah...
```

And I was getting the exact same error as OP.  But after taking a closer look I saw this while reading the [Expo Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-expo-with-firestore)

> React Native Firebase requires custom native code and cannot be used with Expo Go.

And finally had a lead on how to fix the problem.

## **The Fix**

Since we cannot use the react native firebase libraries in our Expo Go project, we instead have to use the plain [Firebase JS SDK](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-firebase-js-sdk).

I installed the sdk in my project like mentioned in the above SDK link.  I already had a firebase config file, but if not you'll need to follow that step too.  Then I simply changed my above code to this

```
import {
  getFunctions,
  httpsCallable,
  HttpsCallableResult,
} from 'firebase/functions';

// some other code

const functions = getFunctions();
const annotateImage = httpsCallable(functions, 'annotateImage');
annotateImage({
  image: {
    content: result.assets[0].base64,
  },
  features: [
    {
      type: 'TEXT_DETECTION',
    },
  ],
  imageContext: {
    languageHints: ['en'],
  },
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
}).then(// blah blah...
```

and everything started working error free!

Answer (score 0):

I have an expo app and used this link...

May be different if you ejected expo or started with bareworkflow

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-expo-with-firestore

have a firebase.js file and import the different modules you will need

showing ours as an example

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import Constants from "expo-constants"
import "firebase/auth"

 // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration -- from firebase console
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: xxxxxxx,
  authDomain: xxxxxxx,
  databaseURL: xxxxxxxxx,
  projectId: xxxxxxxxx,
  storageBucket: xxxxxxxxx,
  messagingSenderId: xxxxxxxxx,
  appId: xxxxxxxxx,
  measurementId: xxxxxxxxx,
 }

// Initialize Firebase
const Firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const firestore = getFirestore(); <--- our added firestore module
export default [Firebase, firestore]
```

be sure you have the @firebase/module-name added per FB package install guide

Comment: Thanks for your response,I ejected my project to BareWorkFlow the major issue is am not able to use native packages which are added in MainApplication.java  like firebase, etc.